# python kill child thread in multithreading

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading

I have this simple program to calculate square root of a series of numbers
I want to terminate the program in case a child thread encounters exception

My code

```
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
import logging
import time
import sys

def gen_sqrt(q):
    while True:
        try :
            num = q.get()
            sqrt = num * num
            logging.debug('Sqrt of %s is %s',num,sqrt)
            q.task_done()
        except Exception as e:
            logging.debug("Can't process num %s, %s",num,str(e))
            exit_app = True

logging.debug('***Spawning Main thread');

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='[%(levelname)s](%(threadName)-10s) %(message)s',)

num_threads = 4
num_q = Queue()
exit_app = False

#for i in range(5):
for i in (1,2,3,4,'x',5):
        num_q.put(i)



for i in range(num_threads):
    if exit_app is True:
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        #print('Exitapp :',exit_app,end='\n')
        worker = Thread(target=gen_sqrt, args=(num_q,))
        worker.daemon = True
        worker.start()

num_q.join();
logging.debug('***Done');
```

Problem is, my code is throwing the exception but not able to exit without keyboard interrupt.

```
output
[DEBUG](MainThread) ***Spawning Main thread
[DEBUG](Thread-1  ) Sqrt of 1 is 1
[DEBUG](Thread-2  ) Sqrt of 2 is 4
[DEBUG](Thread-1  ) Sqrt of 3 is 9
[DEBUG](Thread-3  ) Sqrt of 4 is 16
[DEBUG](Thread-4  ) Can't process num x, can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
[DEBUG](Thread-2  ) Sqrt of 5 is 25
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "sqrt.py", line 42, in <module>
    num_q.join();
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/queue.py", line 86, in join
    self.all_tasks_done.wait()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/threading.py", line 184, in wait
    waiter.acquire()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

I searched stackoverflow, most answers to this kind of problem are ending up with code even bigger than this program

Any quick pythonic way to do the kill

Thanks
Sam

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
import logging
import time
import sys

main_thread = threading.current_thread()

def gen_sqrt(q):
    while True:
        if not main_thread.is_alive():
            break
        try :
            num = q.get()
            sqrt = num * num
            logging.debug('Sqrt of %s is %s',num,sqrt)
            q.task_done()
        except Exception as e:
            logging.debug("Can't process num %s, %s",num,str(e))
            exit_app = True
```